# Android studio saving data that extends Button

Tags: android, arrays, parcelable, state-saving

I'm working on a **minesweeper game** on android studio.What I'm trying to do is to save the state of the game if the user closes the game while playing.I'm having trouble using `parcelable` on a object that extends `Button` Like this:

```
private final Tile[][] mData = new Tile[8][8]; //8x8 grid   
public class Tile extends Button implements Parcelable
{
    private boolean isMine;
    private boolean isFlag;
    private boolean isCovered;
    private int noSurroundingMines;
```

I know i need to use `onSaveInstanceState` and use `Parcelable`

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("test", (Parcelable) mData); <--Error
}
```

> *Error:Inconvertible types;Cannot Cast GameActivity.Tiles to android.Parcelable

I also know that you can't save 2d array and i'm aware of the work around.  I realy want to find out how to save an object that extends button

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to cast `mData` as `Parcelable`?

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("test", (Parcelable) mData);
```

`Tile[][] mData` is a 2 dimensional array and this is not `Parcelable` itself, but its content would be say `myTile=mData[0][1]`.

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("test", myTile);
```

Please read more on OOPs concept.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually using the Parcelable Interface when you are trying to save mData.

What you might want to do is to put the 2d array inside a wrapper that implements Parcelable.

```
public class Minefield implements Parcelable
{
    private Tile[][] mData;

    public Minefield() {
        mData = new Tile[8][8]
    }
}
```

Then in your main activity, create an instance of Minefield if there is no saved state:

```
private final Minefield minefield;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //do stuff with savedInstanceState
    } else {
        minefield = new Minefield();
    }
}
```